# How to normalize pytorch model output to be in range [0,1]

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, normalization, normalize

lets say I have model called UNet

```
output = UNet(input)
```

that output is a vector of grayscale images shape: `(batch_size,1,128,128)`

What I want to do is to normalize each image to be in range `[0,1]`.

I did it like this:

```
for i in range(batch_size):
   output[i,:,:,:] = output[i,:,:,:]/torch.amax(output,dim=(1,2,3))[i]
```

now every image in the output is normalized, but when I'm training such model, pytorch claim it cannot calculate the gradients in this procedure, and I understand why.

my question is what is the right way to normalize image without killing the backpropogation flow?
something like

```
output = UNet(input)
output = output.normalize
output2 = some_model(output)
loss = ..
loss.backward()
optimize.step()
```

my only option right now is adding a sigmoid activation at the end of the UNet but i dont think its a good idea..

update - code (gen2,disc = unet,discriminator models. est_bias is some output):

---

update 2x code:

```
with torch.no_grad():
            est_bias_for_disc = gen2(input_img)

            est_bias_for_disc /= est_bias_for_disc.amax(dim=(1,2,3), keepdim=True)
        disc_fake_hat = disc(est_bias_for_disc.detach())
        disc_fake_loss = BCE(disc_fake_hat, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake_hat)) 

        disc_real_hat = disc(bias_ref)
        disc_real_loss = BCE(disc_real_hat, torch.ones_like(disc_real_hat))
        disc_loss = (disc_fake_loss + disc_real_loss) / 2
        if epoch<=epochs_till_gen2_stop:
            disc_loss.backward(retain_graph=True) # Update gradients    
            opt_disc.step() # Update optimizer
```

then theres seperate training:

```
 opt_gen2.zero_grad()
 est_bias = gen2(input_img)
 est_bias /= est_bias.amax(dim=(1,2,3), keepdim=True)
 disc_fake = disc(est_bias) 
 ADV_loss = BCE(disc_fake, torch.ones_like(disc_fake))
 gen2_loss = ADV_loss
 gen2_loss.backward() 
 opt_gen2.step()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the tensor's value because of the indexing on the batch dimension. Instead, you can perform the operation in vectorized form:

```
output = output / output.amax(dim=(1,2,3), keepdim=True)
```

The `keepdim=True` argument keeps the shape of [`torch.Tensor.amax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.amax.html)'s output equal to that of its inputs allowing you to perform an in-place operation with it.

Comment: thank you! but it still killed the gradient.. do u have any other suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by *killed*? Did you make sure `output` was differentiable (before doing the in-place normalization I mean)?

Comment: yeah. its differentiable without normalization, and the backpropogation optimization works. but when i add this line, pytorch says "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operatio"

Comment: Ok, can you please provide the relevant code and complete error traceback?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and sorry for the delay, i was out of my office. i updated the following code and the error trackback. if i remove line 3 (the normalization), its working fine

Comment: Is `ADV_loss` different from `DV_loss` or is it just a typo?

Comment: oops, yeah its a typo.. its the same loss, sorry

Comment: This is strange unless you are backpropagating multiple times maybe?

Comment: i tried playing with it.. and the only time i manage to have no error, when calculating all of this procces with torch.no_grad, which is obviously not what I need, its just showing that when gradients are not calculated, no problem occure. that means that this line break the gradient. do u have any other suggestion for normalizaiton?

Comment: Are you back-propagating multiple times?

Comment: i dont think i am. there is a two seperate training happening one after the other, but i dont think its back propagating multiple times.. I updated the code up in the post. The first part, is training the discriminator, and it has not problem because it takes the variable est_bias_for_disc without gradients, then theres a second train for the unet called 'gen2'

Comment: Thank you, to avoid any confusion though only provide one version of your code: preferably the latest one which fails (with the in place normalization and both backward calls) along with the full error backtrace.

Comment: this is the one and only version i have.. i didnt changed it. i just added the training that happend before the training that produce the error. so about the back propagating multiple times, is it count as 2 times propagating? i dont think so because its diffrenet networks and variables

Comment: Have you tried doing `output = output / output.amax(dim=(1,2,3), keepdim=True)`?

Comment: omg it worked! i was so skeptical about this minor change but it actaully made the diffrenece. well played. thank you! edit your answer so i can mark it as the solution

Comment: The difference is that `output /= ...` will in place modify `output` while `output = output / ...` will make a copy. Not quite sure why this is an issue, it might be because of the backpropagation following it. Glad it worked out for you ;)

Comment: hm, when I use this line, it does not change my output. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @MatécsaAndrea Can you be more specific, did you check the content of your tensor?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I checked the content of the tensor and nothing happened. In the end I solved my calculations in a different way, but I would like to know why this did not do any change. 
My "output" has the form [4, 1, 512, 512]. Does this help in any way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the normalize function:

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torch.nn.functional as F
>>> x = torch.tensor([[3.,4.],[5.,6.],[7.,8.]])
>>> x = F.normalize(x, dim = 0)
>>> print(x)

  tensor([[0.3293, 0.3714],
          [0.5488, 0.5571],
          [0.7683, 0.7428]])
```

This will give a differentiable tensor as long as `out` is not used.

Comment: it worked! are you sure that the '.normalize' procedure doesnt destory the gradient? and what do u mean "This will give a differentiable tensor as long as out is not used." who is 'out' in your equation? 'x'..?

Comment: @AdarCohen Are you sure this is the normalization you are looking for? This seems to be on the first axis only...

Comment: mmhm.. u are right, i think it divided the set of images by a one factor which is the maximum value of all of the images, instead of divide the maximum of each image to it self. how can we solved it? i can run a training with batch size 1, but i belive there is a better solution